# Case expression with a parameter fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

I want to only use the where condition if Make is not equal to '0'. This is what I have tried. This is a snippet from the stored proc. Query works only when Make is not 0. When it is '0' it fails.

This is not a null check. @Make is a varchar. How it is implemented is either it will be '0' or it will be a string e.g 'mazda'.

```
select *
from In_Inventory
where
and Make = case 
when @Make != '0'
Then @Make
end
```

Comment: Just for your own understanding, the reason this fails is because your case only returns a value when make != 0. If Make would be 0 your query would just read "and Make =". Then again, there's no reason to use a case here. See below for better approaches (such as using an OR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT
*
FROM In_Inventory
WHERE @Make = 0
OR Make = @Make
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it isn't going to work in this scenario. What I need is if the value coming into the @Make variable in the stored proc is equal to '0' do not filter on make. If the variable is equal to anything else filter on make. "WHERE Make = 0" would be never be used because the Make column is a varchar with values like "mazda" etc

Comment: @JeremyKern I've just updated my answer. If @ Make = 0 then don't do anything, otherwise do Make = @ Make. Is this what you're after?

Comment: This looks to be what I am after. I'll try it when I'm back at work tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `case` expression to return syntactic elements (such as a `where` clause), only values. However, you could get the same behavior with a simple `in` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM   In_Inventory
WHERE  @Make IN ('0', Make)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT
*
FROM In_Inventory
WHERE @Make = 0
OR Make = @Make
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM In_Inventory
WHERE (
        Make = 0
        OR Make = @Make
        )
```